# How to configuration keepalived on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, keepalived, vrrp

I rad some article.
[Keepalived over GRE tunnel for failover on VPS environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/186987/keepalived-over-gre-tunnel-for-failover-on-vps-environment/187032#187032)

http://blog.killtheradio.net/how-tos/keepalived-haproxy-and-failover-on-the-cloud-or-any-vps-without-multicast/

but, I don't know how to configuration? and How to call this architecture?

only I Know that How to config Master/Backup configuration at keepalived.

What I want to know that How does work keepalived?

I want to design this....

```
                XMPP Server(EC2) 
                       |
-------------------------------------------------
keepalived Master(EC2) - keepalived Backup(EC2)
HAProxy #1               HAProxy#2      
-------------------------------------------------
                       |

Casandra#1   Casandra#2  Casandra#3  Casandra#4
```

---

Thanks!
but What I want to know how to work on keepalived with unicast patche modul.
ELB is expansive. 

and this is first totaly design.

[Flow]

ELB --> XMPP Server --> ELB --> Casandra

```
                      ELB
                       |
XMPP#1        XMPP#2       XMPP#3       XMPP#4 
                       |
                      ELB
                       |
Casandra#1   Casandra#2  Casandra#3  Casandra#4
```

and change first design.

[Flow]

ELB --> XMPP Server --> HAProxy Master(Casandra Farm) --> Casandra

```
                      ELB
                       |
XMPP#1        XMPP#2      XMPP#3       XMPP#4 
                       |
-------------------------------------------------
keepalived Master(EC2) - keepalived Backup(EC2)
HAProxy#1                HAProxy#2      
-------------------------------------------------
                       |

Casandra#1   Casandra#2  Casandra#3  Casandra#4
```

this is second.

[Flow]

ELB --> HAProxy(XMPP Farm) --> XMPP Server --> HAProxy(Casandra Farm) --> Casanda

It's OK?

```
                      ELB
                       |
HAProxy#1   HAProxy#2   HAProxy#3   HAProxy#4
XMPP#1       XMPP#2     XMPP#3      XMPP#4 
                       |
Casandra#1   Casandra#2  Casandra#3  Casandra#4
```

Comment: see this answer.
http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.linux.keepalived.devel/month=20120101
Can I use the virtaul_router_id ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not intimately familiar with keepalived/haproxy, why not just use the AWS ELB?

As for running haproxy on your own (if you're deadset on doing that), I presume you're trying to bounce connections from XMPP server to Casandra 1-4.  Why not just install haproxy on the XMPP box? You can configure haproxy like you normally would and then simply point XMPP at 127.0.0.1 - Then you've got 5 boxes in your setup instead of 7.